# CKEditor widget double click to open dialog does not work

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

I have created the most simple widget which consists of a single div with a class. The template is;

```
<div class="simple" data-padding="false"></header>
```

The Dialog contains 1 checkbox to change the padding.

This widget works all ok, is upcasted nicely, shows the yellow line around it when you hover over it. However it is impossible to double click on it to open the dialog, nothing happens, no console errors as well. I should expect that double clicking inside the div should open the dialog.

When a second div is nested, which is set to be the editable and some padding is added to the main div, it is possible to double click on the padding area between the two divs which opens the Dialog, that is however of course not what I want..

What is going wrong here, is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially solved it by adding a listener to the double click event;

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('simple', {
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.on( 'doubleclick', function(e) {
            var ClickedWidget = e.editor.widgets.widgetHoldingFocusedEditable;
            if (ClickedWidget != null && ClickedWidget.name == 'simple') {
                ClickedWidget.edit();
            }
        });
```

This worked nicely but got in the way with selecting text in an editable element. That thus also explains why it is setup like that.

So to solve this properly I created a plugin that shows a context menu on right clicking the widget, with the options to edit and remove. I have made this plugin available on CKEditor website for others to use;

http://ckeditor.com/addon/widgetcontextmenu